# Is the Boeing 777X being certified as a derivative of the 777 Classic?

Tags: faa-regulations, boeing-777, aircraft-certification

Given the corner cutting Boeing did with the Max certification, is the FAA allowing the 777X to be certified as a derivative (easier) of the 777 Classic or requiring a new Type Certificate? (harder)

The wings are new, the engines are new, the flight deck is new (from the 787 I understand), the weight is higher and the fuselage longer.

Comment: It'll probably be certed as a 777 derivative, but the key thing is maintaining a common type rating requiring no pilot sim time to convert.  That's what drives all of this.  Can't say for certain, but in my experience the major factor in achieving a common type rating is a common cockpit with as little variation as possible between variants.  A new flight deck makes it certain in my mind that there will have to be a new type rating for crews, even if it's on the same TC.

Comment: @JohnK B737NG type ratings could be obtained in a B737C sim in the past, followed by some sessions Differences Training in a B737NG sim.

Comment: @Koyovis My type rating was in the CRJ line, and moving to different models only required a class/CBT session with no sim, even though you'd be going from a hard wing CRJ200 to a slatted, FADEC CRJ700.  When the 1000 was brought out, Transport Canada put their foot down and demanded dedicated sim time as well, although it was just a short session including demonstrating you knew how long the thing was by doing a U turn lol.  But just the requirement for a little sim was a disaster marketing-wise.

Comment: Related (general rule, not applicable to each cases, thus not a dupe): [How are evolution and variants of aircraft considered by certification authorities?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/9277/how-are-evolution-and-variants-of-aircraft-considered-by-certification-authoriti)

Answer (score 4):

**Yes, Boeing applied for an amendment to the existing 777 type certificate:**

> On April 19, 2017 (for the Model 777-8 airplane), and May 12, 2015 (for the 777-9 airplane), Boeing applied for an **amendment to Type Certificate (TC) No. T00001SE** to include the new Model 777-8 and 777-9 airplanes. These airplanes are constructed with new carbon-fiber-reinforced plastic (CFRP) wings with folding wingtips.
>
> The Model 777-9 airplane, a derivative of the Model 777-300ER airplane currently approved under TC No. T00001SE, is a stretched-fuselage, large, twin-engine airplane with seating for 408 passengers and a maximum takeoff weight of 775,000 pounds.
>
> The Model 777-8 airplane, a shortened-body derivative of the Model 777-9 airplane, is a large, twin-engine airplane with seating for 359 passengers and a maximum takeoff weight of 775,000 pounds.

<sup>([federalregister.gov](https://www.federalregister.gov/documents/2018/05/18/2018-10576/special-conditions-the-boeing-company-model-777-8-and-777-9-airplanes-folding-wingtips#h-8), emphasis mine)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Boeing [claims](https://www.boeing.com/777x/reveal/777x-flight-deck-reveal/) it shares the 777 type rating and has a common type with the 787, which it says reduces training requirements.

[image]

Comment: Does it mean the firsts 777 and the 787 share a common type rating?

Comment: @ManuH In Europe, **yes**: [What does “share a type rating” mean?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/54238/what-does-share-a-type-rating-mean)